# Why is "reducing Hamiltonian energy" also optimizing a Quantum Machine Learning model?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hamiltonian-simulation, optimization, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

From what I observed, most hybrid qml architectures surround the ideas of Hamiltonian states, and it seems like our goal to optimize a circuit is to keep energy states as low as possible. But why is that? How is it related to the performance of a model?

Comment: Any optimization problem can be cast as finding the ground state of a Hamiltonian, which happens to be a convenient for quantum systems because Hamiltonians are often physically the thing that can be engineered

Comment: @QuantumMechanic so how exactly do we cast the "errors" in our ml model as Hamiltonian states?

Comment: My guess is something to do with the energy of a state being a proxy of the "errors" - you take a fixed Hamiltonian to set up the problem, then try to find the state with the lowest energy for that Hamiltonian as a proxy for finding the optimum solution. But I'm not sure, depends on the QML architecture